# Tkinter regular statements not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, chat

So i've been working at this very simple chatprogram, but no matter what I do I just cant seem to get it to work properly. for some reason regular statements like "state = DISABLED" and "sticky = N+S+E+W" are no longer working and just resulting in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\K2\Desktop\Projekt 1\chWin.py", line 60, in <module>
    chWin = chWin()
  File "C:\Users\K2\Desktop\Projekt 1\chWin.py", line 12, in __init__
    self.chatWin.configure( bg = '#747371', fg = 'orange', state = DISABLED )
NameError: global name 'DISABLED' is not defined
```

I'm really out of ideas and can't find the answer anywhere. Maybe it's really simple, dont know! Please help!
`

```
import tkinter as GUI

switch = False

class chWin( GUI.Tk ):
    def __init__( self ):
        GUI.Tk.__init__( self )


        #Medalandefönster
        self.chatWin = GUI.Text( self )
        self.chatWin.configure( bg = '#747371', fg = 'orange', state = DISABLED )
        self.chatWin.grid( row = 0, column = 0, sticky = N+S+E+W)

        #Scrollbaren
        self.scrl = GUI.Scrollbar(self)
        self.scrl.grid( row = 0, column = 0, sticky = N+S+E+W)

        #Gör så att scrollbar fungerar

        self.scrl.configure( command = self.chatWin.yview)
        self.chatWin.configure( yscrollcommand = self.scrl.set, state = DISABLED )

        #Medalandeinput
        self.msg = GUI.Entry( self )
        self.msg.configure( bg = '#262626', fg = 'orange' )
        self.msg.grid( row = 1, sticky = N+S+E+W)

        #Skicka-knapp
        self.btn = GUI.Button( self, text = '<< Send >>', command = self.sendMsg )
        self.btn.configure( bg = 'orange', fg = 'black' )
        self.btn.bind('<Button-1>', self.sendMsg)
        self.btn.grid( row = 1, sticky = N+S+E+W)

        #Binder "Enter" till knappen
        self.msg.bind('<Return>', self.sendMsg )

    def sendMsg(self, event=None):
        global switch
        send = self.msg.get()
        print (send)
        if len(send) < 1:
            pass
        else:
            ext = 'Me:\n  '
            ext = ext + send
            self.chatWin.configure(state = NORMAL)
            self.chatWin.insert(END, ext + '\n')
            self.chatWin.yview(END)
            self.chatWin.configure(state = DISABLED)
            sak = ext + '\n'
            switch = True
            while switch == True:
                mess = send.encode()
                s.send(mess)
                print('client sent: ', mess)
                switch = False
            msg.delete(0, END)

chWin = chWin()
chWin.mainloop()
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'd need `GUI.DISABLED` since `DISABLED` is part of the `tkinter` namespace and you have:

```
import tkinter as GUI
```

Same goes for `N`, `E`, `W`, `S`, `NORMAL`, `END` -- `GUI.N`, `GUI.E`, ...

Comment: Thnx so much for the help! Worked like a chram!

Comment: No problem. Happy to do it. :)